# Changes to navigation settings aren't saved

Tags: navigation, 2007

I have a publishing site, and am trying to reorder the pages via the Site Navigation Settings pages (`Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation`.)

I move the pages up and down in the `Navigation Editing and Sorting` section, but when I click OK, none of the alterations are persisted.

Is there any reason why this might happen?  I created the pages via a Powershell script, and originally used Gary Lapointe's `gl-setnavigationnodes` ([link](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/more-site-navigation-settings-commands.html)) to set the navigation order via a script.

**UPDATE**: Looking in the logs I see this related error:

> Unable to retrieve QuickLaunch SPNavigationNodeCollection from Web at: http://server/sitecollection/web. The SPNavigation store is likely corrupt.

If I browse the SPWeb in question, I can see that web.Navigation.QuickLaunch is null, which must be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this issue is only occurring if I use `stsadm -o createweb` to create the web.

What I was doing was, in a powershell script, creating the web with `stsadm -o createweb`, and then activating the publishing feature on the web (GUID 94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb).

I find if I do everything else the same, but create the web with calls to the object model, I don't get this issue with a corrupt SPNavigation store.

So is it a bug in stsadm??